# How to get a typed value from an Input?

Tags: reactstrap

I would like to get a typed value from a ReactStrap Input component, via the onChange function.
The aim is to use a `text` input only but be able to get a specific typed value (String or Number in my example below).

```
<Input valueAs="String" name="input1" type="text" onChange={this.onChange}></Input>
<Input valueAs="Number" name="input2" type="text" onChange={this.onChange}></Input>
```

You can see the expected type is defined by the `valueAs` attribute.
I expect to get an event in `this.onChange` with:

- a value as a String for Input 1
- a value as a Number for Input 2

What is the best way to do this with React / Reactstrap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Input` component of `reactstrap` does not have a property called `valueAs`. To get value in a format you need, you can do:

```
<Input name="input1" type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(`${e.target.value}`)}/>
{/* to make it integer you can add unary plus sign like so: */}
{/* this.onChange(+e.target.value) */}
```